# Typewriter effect in a loop jquery - How to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve a typewriter effect in jQuery and this is what I have achieved so far.

```
var text = 'Loading ...';

//text is split up to letters
$.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter){

    //we add 100*i ms delay to each letter 
    setTimeout(function(){

        //we add the letter to the container
        $('#container').html($('#container').html() + letter);

    }, 100*i);
});
```

This is give the effect one time, but I want it to run in a loop continuously.

I have set up a fiddle for what I have tried so far [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/XP5M9/1/)

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just maintain a counter, and reset to `0` at the end of the string.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/QPNTq/

```
var chars = 'Loading ...'.split('');
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (i < chars.length) {
        container.innerHTML += chars[i++];
    } else {
        i = 0;
        container.innerHTML = "";
    }
}, 100);
```

No need for `.each()` or any other kind of loop this way. Much simpler.

Comment: simpler and less 'interval' dependent. Thanks for this.

Comment: @harsha: You're welcome. I just gave an update since I was actually wiping out the last `.` character.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code within a function (something named `repeat`) and then call it using `setInterval` like

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#container').html(''); //clear the container
    repeat();
}, 1100)
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XP5M9/6/)

Comment: In the fiddle you posted , the '.' is getting misplaced

Comment: @harsha instead of 1000 use `1100` see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XP5M9/6/ because it is taking 1100 milliseconds by the `setTimeout` method hence it is affecting the `setInterval`.

Comment: A simple query. why the 1100

Comment: @harsha if you check setTimout `100*i` you're totally it takes 11 times starting from 0..10 iteration.  hence 1100.  Hope you understood

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XP5M9/4/)

```
var text = 'Loading ...';

setInterval(function(){

$('#container').html("");

//text is split up to letters
    $.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter){

        //we add 100*i ms delay to each letter 
        setTimeout(function(){

            //we add the letter to the container
            $('#container').html($('#container').html() + letter);

        }, 100*i);
    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: In the fiddle you posted , the '.' is getting misplaced